What does the number on the cars' windshields mean in the Golden Triangle Special Economic Zone, Laos?
I was watching some vlog that mentioned that cars in the Golden Triangle Special Economic Zone, Laos, always have a number on their windshields. As is typical with such vlogs, no insight is given, which leaves me wondering: What does the number on the cars' windshields mean in the Golden Triangle Special Economic Zone, Laos?

Screenshot from the vlog showing the number on a car's windshield:


If you look at Google Street View you'll see that not all cars have those numbers (though those which don't may be cars from outside the zone), and that all those that have such numbers don't have license plates, so it's probably the local equivalent of a license plate.
